# SVN commit error when adding a file

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

A couple days ago, I started getting an error when attempting to add a file to our project that is checked into SVN.  Checking out and updating still works fine but if I try to add a file I get an error that makes no sense.

I'm using Eclipse 4.2 and the latest version of Subclipse but I also get the same error using TortoiseSVN 1.7.10.

The error I get is:

```
    svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
    svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: Processing PROPFIND request response failed: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "language". (/svn/myproject/trunk/database/sql/2.11/test.xml) 
svn: E175002: Processing PROPFIND request response failed: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "language". (/svn/myproject/!svn/wrk/2bc65adb-3a01-0010-a3f6-67fdfc8c148b/trunk/database/sql/2.11/test.xml) 
    svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: Processing PROPFIND request response failed: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "language". (/svn/myproject/trunk/database/sql/2.11/test.xml) 
svn: E175002: Processing PROPFIND request response failed: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "language". (/svn/myproject/!svn/wrk/2bc65adb-3a01-0010-a3f6-67fdfc8c148b/trunk/database/sql/2.11/test.xml)
```

Things I've tried:

- Cleanup and refresh with both Eclipse and Tortoise
- Disconnect the project from the repository and reconnect it
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Tortoise
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Subclipse
- Checked out the repository into another project and tried to add a file in the 'new' project but I still get the same error in the 'new' project.

**UPDATE:** When I VPN into my office's private network and use the internal IP address for the SVN repository it works just fine.  Which seems to point to either the new internet provider I'm using (Charter); or to AVG which I recently switched to.  I did try the "disable AVG" option in AVG but still I still get the same error.

Does anyone know what this error is and how to fix it?

Comment: Are there any commit hooks in your SVN repo which might be trying to validate the XML file mentioned (test.xml)? This looks like an XML parsing problem (e.g. missing quote in the XML file).

Comment: you can replace test.xml with monkey.txt.  This same error happens with any file of any format that I try to add.  It isn't validating anything in test.xml.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot directly answer your problem, but here is some other info that will help:

- Refresh/Cleanup fix very specific problems only.  Cleanup is mainly meant to be run when there is an unexpected crash in the middle of something like update/commit.  Cleanup will remove the locks on the working copy and complete any queued transactions.  Refresh is mainly an issue for GUI tools to force them to run svn status and refresh their icons.
- Uninstall/reinstall is almost always pointless.  It is not like you have corrupt files.
- A fresh checkout is sometimes useful to try, especially if doing so is not painful.

Your error is happening during the HTTP conversation between the client and server.  PROPFIND is one of the low-level HTTP requests that the SVN client issues to the server.  I would look for proxy servers, firewalls, anti-virus (particularly the latter) that might be getting in the way of the HTTP conversation and corrupting the data.  That is what it sounds like here.  Something is corrupting the response to the PROPFIND request.  It could be a problem with the SVN Server, but I think that is unlikely.  I think it has to be something sitting between the client and server that is interfering with the conversation.

Comment: This gives me something to go on at least.  I recently changed to Charter Internet.  I also started using AVG so either of these could be getting in the middle.  I disabled AVG and still got the error.  When I VPN into my office's private network and try with the internal IP address everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when trying to add my project to SVN:

```
svn: E175002: Processing PROPFIND request response failed: Open quote is expected for attribute "lang" associated with an  element type  "html". (/svn/trunk/Tools/Java/Epsd2Jira)
```

The root cause turned out to be proxying Eclipse traffic through a company internal web gateway. As the SVN is within the company intranet, changing Eclipse network settings to use direct connection fixed the issue and I was able to commit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using Aptana. Mostly this fixes itself by doing a cleanup, then a refresh, and then a cleanup again

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I tried to install SVN client on all 3 of my computers (vista, xp, windows 7), all has same problem. It did not have problem when I add commit from my own server (the SVN server is in the server). It did not have problem my friend try from his own computer. I tried to reboot router, disable anti virus, non worked. I tried to reinstall so many time both SVN server and my SVN client, still same problem.

Finally, I changed from http to https, and it works fine.